# R 2.14.1 OS X dens() of lessR does not take sample() data as input

Tags: r

**R version 2.14.1    Platform: i386-apple-darwin9.8.0/i386 (32-bit)**

**Objective:**
Use function `dens()` of library `lessR` to plot a normal density curve and a general density curve superimposed over a histogram.

**Problem:**
While generating the data using e.g. `rnorm()` or `rbinom()` works well, running it on data generated by `sample()` returns this error:

```
Error in if (from == to) rep.int(from, length.out) else as.vector(c(from,  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

**MWE:**

```
library(lessR)
data <- data.frame(col=sample(20))
y <- data$col
dens(y)
```

**Question:**
What causes the problem and what do I have to do if I want to have a data frame with a single column, let us say, which would contain twenty rows of values generated by the `sample()` function and use them as an input for the `dens()`?

**Update (2012-11-17):**
I have updated R to version 2.15.2 and `lessR` to version 2.6 (both are the latest available).

Using the data provided by @Roland, the error is now:

```
Error in seq.default(x.min, x.max, length = 200) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

I can understand why it does happen and allowing `sample()` to use a single value more than one leads to a correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of `lessR` appears not to provide a function `dens` anymore, instead there is a function `Density`.

Would you consider updating your R version and the package? Why are you using the 32-bit version of R? On a Mac you should be able to use the 64-bit version.

I had a look at function `dens` from `lessR_2.1.1`. I could not reproduce your error (because you did not use `set.seed` to make your code reproducible). Instead I got `Error in seq(min.x, max.x, length = 200) : Object 'min.x' not found` with `y <- c(3, 4, 8, 1, 6, 14, 20, 5, 13, 17, 19, 10, 2, 12, 7, 9, 18, 11, 15, 16)`.

Here is an excerpt from the function code:

```
d.gen <- suppressWarnings(density(x, bw, ...))

        mx <- mean(x)

        # min and max x coordinates for graph, make symmetric
        min.dev.x <- min(d.gen$x) - mx
        max.dev.x <- max(d.gen$x) - mx
        if (abs(min.dev.x) > abs(max.dev.x)) {
          min.x <- min(d.gen$x)
          max.x <- mx + abs(min.dev.x)
        }
        if (abs(max.dev.x) > abs(min.dev.x)) {
          min.x <- mx - abs(max.dev.x)
          max.x <- max(d.gen$x)
        }
```

Note that the code does not define `min.x` and `max.x`, if `abs(min.dev.x) == abs(max.dev.x)`, which is a bug. Of course that is easily fixed by changing the second if condition to `if (abs(max.dev.x) >= abs(min.dev.x)) {`.

There might be other bugs, but it's not worth fixing a function from an archived version of a utility package. Of course, I get a similar error with the new `Density` function and indeed it contains the same bug.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis, I now understand why it happens. I have edited my question to answer some of your question. In addition, I am using the 32-bit version of R because one of my computers, the one that I am currently working on, is simply a 32-bit machine (iMac 2006). Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as the developer of lessR I found the bug.  What happened is that I had a > and a < condition for centering the density plot, but no = condition.  This = condition was triggered from the call to sample(20) because the result was the sequential integers from 1 to 20. Obviously a valid set, but one which triggered the = condition in my code and a condition that I had not previously tested.  Changing a > to >= has fixed the bug. The fix will be on CRAN when I upload the next version around Dec 10. The maintainers are discouraging frequent updates to CRAN, so I need to wait until Dec to update.

For now, if you wish to get a density plot using your example, run the following R code.

```
y <- sample(20)
dy <- density(y)
plot(dy)
```

Also, when I began this project almost 4 years ago, I did not have a plan to produce a systematic system for data analysis with about 43 different functions.  As such my initial naming schemes for functions did not generalize very well as the system grew from just a few functions, so I have gradually evolved a system that will not change in the future.  Each function can be referred to by its full name, such as Density, or now by a usual two character abbreviation, dn in this case.  I decided for consistency sake to make the abbreviations two characters, which are also lower case.  The goal is to produce standard data analysis procedures such as a Histogram or hs, a ScatterPlot or sp, a BoxPlot or bx with very little work and with provided color themes for the graphs. The default color theme is blue, but can be changed easily with the set function.

Comment: I thank you as well and cheers for the lessR library. I am an R beginner and find it very useful for my initial work.